# How to jitter points on both axes

Tags: python, scatter-plot, categorical-data

I have 2 categorical variables in a dataframe.

```
abc = ['A','A','B','B','B','A','B','B','B','A','A','A',]
xyz = ['X','X','X','X','Y','Y','X','X','Y','Y','X','Y',]
df = pd.DataFrame([abc, xyz]).T
df.columns=['abc','xyz']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   abc xyz
0    A   X
1    A   X
2    B   X
3    B   X
4    B   Y
5    A   Y
6    B   X
7    B   X
8    B   Y
9    A   Y
10   A   X
11   A   Y
```

I want to create a scatterplot with points jittered along both axes to avoid overlap.

I tried following:

```
sns.stripplot(data=df, x='abc', y='xyz', jitter=True, dodge=True)
plt.show()
```

I get following plot:

[image]

I find that jitter is along X-axis but not along Y-axis.  How  can jitter be achieved on both axes?